# Winform Datagridview. Column List Resets after build

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This DGV is in a form that has been in production for months.  I edited the form to add a checkbox to an unrelated function on the page.  Built the solution and the DGV suddenly had all of its columns visible and all of the column prameters reset back to default.

I thought 'Well, thats wierd'.  Changed the DGV back to what it was, hit the debug and ran the form. Everything looked good.  Stopped the debug and lo and behold, all the columns were reset again.

I thought 'Well, thats irritating'.  So I deleted the DGV, added a new one, set it up again and the new one did the same thing.  Then I started playing with the columns and the DGV will only reset if certain columns are the only ones showing.  I have stopped the bad behavior by leaving the columns that I want in and a few columns that I didnt want but are set to invisible.

I have not changed the datasset, I have not made any changes to the underlying data tables or stored procedures.  But just to make sure I built another form with a DGV bound to the same Data set, no problems.

Not sure what to do at this point.  Thing is working now but it was very annoying to have to spend a half hour trying to figure out why VS kept redesigning my form.

Has anyone else had this issue?  I would include code but I dont think its a code issue. Visual Studio Voodo maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I Had something similar, but different with DGV,

it was too long ago to remmember, but i remmember i put code to add columns in the constructor, which made the Designer to always add more and more.

.

Another possibility is that you have a different constructor made for the form, and Winforms designer does not call InitiateComponent() from it.

sorry i couldn't be of more help.

Comment: I spent a good bit of time stepping through code until I realized that it was the build proccess that was doing it and not anything that I had inadvertantly done.  I pulled this version out of the vault, added a check box and bammo! problem.